# Finding the inverse of a map given in vector form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inverse-function

The question asks me to find the inverse map $ \mathbf\Phi^{-1} $, of:

$$ \mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{x})= \mathbf{n\lor(x \lor n)} + \alpha\mathbf{(n \cdotp x)n} $$
for $\alpha$ such that the inverse exists. I'm not quite sure how to do this without finding the matrix representing the map and then taking its inverse (for $\alpha$ such that it exists) which in this case would be rather messy.
I've tried setting  $ \mathbf{x'} = \mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{x})$ and rearranging but this only yields: $$ \mathbf{x'}= \mathbf{x}  -(1-\alpha)(\mathbf{x \cdot n})\mathbf{n} $$ and I don't see how this will let me express $\mathbf{x}$ explicitly in terms of $\mathbf{x'}$ to find the inverse function, without dotting or crossing either side, which I believe is not allowed as such a step isn't reversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector.

It is easy to see that, when $\alpha=1$, the two terms of the sum are the components of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ parallel and orthogonal to $\mathbf{n}$. So in such a case their sum is exactly $\mathbf{x}$, i.e. $\Phi(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}$.

When $\alpha\neq 1$, the component parallel to $\mathbf{n}$ is incremented by a factor $\alpha$, so the inverse is obtained simply decrementing such a component by a factor $1/\alpha$:
$$ 
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\Phi}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{n} \wedge (\mathbf{y} \wedge \mathbf{n}) + \frac{1}{\alpha}\,(\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{y})\,\mathbf{n} $$

The case to exclude is $\alpha=0.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this makes sense to me (would up vote but I'm new to this and it's not letting me). One question: surely there still exists an inverse when $ \alpha=1 $? In this case, wouldn't the function just be its own inverse?

Comment: @AASJC: exactly, $\Phi^{-1}=\Phi.$

Comment: What concerns me is that the question says "for alpha such that the inverse exists" - but according to this the inverse exists for all alpha?

Comment: @AASJC: no, the case $\alpha=0$ is excluded, I wrote that in the answer.

Comment: Apologies - overlooked that. Thank you very much!